Movie where the main character has writer's block
The movie starts with a writer who has writer's block.  His therapist tells him to write one very short, very bad story. The guy has a dream about walking his dog and a woman makes a comment about the dog. He quickly gets up and writes down that bit of a story.
As the movie progresses, he continues to write, then the woman that he is writing about shows up in his life. He finds that he can change her behavior by changing what he writes.

The irony of someone voting to close this question as "needs more details" when it's been answered is not lost on anyone, I hope.

I haven't seen it - but I think it might be "Ruby Sparks".
The lead is struggling to write his next book, and sees a therapist.

His therapist tasks him to write about someone who likes his dog, Scotty. After a dream in which he meets a woman, Calvin is inspired to write about her, admitting that he is falling in love with his character, "Ruby Sparks".

After writing that the woman falls in love with him, he finds her in his house.

Calvin writes a passage about Ruby falling in love with him before falling asleep at his typewriter. The next day, he is stunned to find Ruby in his kitchen, a living person, who believes they are dating.

Here are the main characters:


This is Ruby Sparks (2012)

Calvin (Paul Dano) wrote a best-selling novel 10 years ago, when he
was just 19. He lives a comfortable existence off the largesse of this
early success, but suffers severe writer’s block each time he sits
before his typewriter to write something new. His therapist (Elliott
Gould) gives him an assignment to help break him out of his funk: he
asks him to imagine meeting someone who’s kind to his dog.
For some reason this works, and while he’s asleep Calvin meets Ruby
Sparks (Zoe Kazan). A fit of inspiration follows, as he spends days
and nights writing about her, detailing the story of her life. She is,
literally, the girl of his dreams.
D Magazine




